flutter how to change copy/pause menu theme in common ThemeData(darktheme & lighttheme)
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:test/config/app_theme.dart';

class LoginInfoFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginInfoFormField(
      {required this.controller,
      required this.hintText,
      required this.labelText,
      this.validator,
      this.onChanged,
      this.inputFormatters,
      this.focusNode,
      this.enableSuggestions = true,
      this.autocorrect = true,
      this.obscureText = false,
      this.suffixIcon,
      super.key});
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final void Function(String)? onChanged;
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final String labelText;
  final String hintText;
  final bool enableSuggestions;
  final bool autocorrect;
  final bool obscureText;
  final Widget? suffixIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Key: ${key.toString()}');
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(),
      child: TextFormField(
        // key: key,
        controller: controller,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        validator: validator,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        enableSuggestions: enableSuggestions,
        autocorrect: autocorrect,
        inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
        style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondaryContainer),
    );
  }
}


Flutter version  3.22.2
when wrap with Theme widget to TextFormField,i get the first image style.
In project,may be that there are many textformfield.
TextSelectionThemeData TextSelectionThemeData({
  Color? cursorColor,
  Color? selectionColor,
  Color? selectionHandleColor,
})

TextSelectionThemeData don't work for copy /pause theme.
how to change copy/pause menu theme in common ThemeData(darktheme & lighttheme)
